# EC2 Nginx configuration - return to original URL after Prerender

Tags: nginx, saas, prerender

all tutorials I found imply a Node server running in EC2. On Node a Prerender Server is running. Nginx x is configured to take indexing bots calls and run through Prerender and return the prerendered page.
An example [here](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/how-to-set-up-your-own-prerender-environment-with-aws-ec2-a14451f857bf).

However, all tutorials assume the SPA is ran in the same Node instance and Nginx returns to the local SPA (index.html). I am building my prerender service as a SaaS. My SPA is in Heroku and my prerender service is running in EC2. I sincerely don't really understand the Nginx syntax and logic, I am a Javascript developer and I am looking for some help to direct from Nginx back to my SPA (the URL being prerendered) instead of a local index.html.

The generic Nginx configuration is like follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name *.example.com;

root   /home/prerender;
index  index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}

location @prerender {
    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "127.0.0.1:3000";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
    if ($prerender = 0) {
        rewrite .* /index.html break; // HERE I WANT TO SEND BACK TO MY PRERENDERED URL INSTEAD OF INDEX.HTML
    }
}
```

}

My $request_uri is the rendered url preceded by a "/" like

> /https://example.com/some_page

I feel I need to do a rewrite or something and get rid of the first "/" though I do not really understand the concept of rewrite, redirect, return. I red the documentation but I probably miss too much of the Nginx culture to understand what I actually need to do.

So if you are experience with Nginx, SaaS and Prerender, I'd love to hear from you about the proper way to get back to my SPA.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You would just want to change this to be the URL of your Prerender server:

```
set $prerender "127.0.0.1:3000";
```

The rest looks good. The config will detect a crawler like Googlebot and proxy the request to the Prerender server so that the crawler will receive the HTML instead of the javascript.

Any requests from normal users will receive your normal javascript page. Feel free to email us at support@prerender.io if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. This was really kind of you. Unfortunately this does not seem to work.

Comment: Before the change, when I used to rewrite with the index.html, Prerender would prerender the local index.html, which is just a <h1>Hi</h1> Consequent calls for the same url (I use curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit" http(s)://myprerenderserver.com/mySPAurl.) return my index.html cause this is what was prerendered before. However, after change,new urls return a 404. What I understand is that when I prerend a url this happens: search the cache DB (I use Redis), if not found, redirect to SPA. The case when the page is not already prerendered is not covered. Fetch as goole returns "not found" (404).

Comment: Before and after your suggested change:
Before: curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit" https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/hobbies/classic_cars  --  returns "Hi" (the local index.html was prerendered).
After: curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit" https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/fishing -- returns 404, there is no scenario in which the page is being rendered. Looks like I should somehow go back to SPA (mimicking the rewrite to index.html, instead of set $prerender "127.0.0.1:3000";

Comment: You don't want to access your Prerender server URL directly. You want to just access your website normally but with a crawler user agent like curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit" https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/fishing . Also, if your URL is render.activitree.com then you should put that in the config instead of 127.0.0.1:3000. So can you try set $prerender "render.activitree.com";

Comment: I think you gave me the right hints and now I understand how it works. However, when I run curl -vvv -A "facebookexternalhit" https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/education/french, I see in the Prerender log (tail on Node console log): { source: 'network', level: 'error', text: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',  url: 'https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/education/french' ... Does this mean that my Prerender in Node in EC2 cannot contact my SPA in heroku.com?

Comment: Maybe 404 issue is related to this ?! https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/230

Comment: I don't think that's related to that github issue. This part is weird: url: 'render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/…'. I wouldn't expect to see render.activitree.com in there. Is it possible that your middleware is adding render.activitree.com onto the URL twice or something? What URL do you see in the Prerender server logs when the server says "getting https://www.example.com/"?

Comment: On curl -v -A "facebookexternalhit" https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all  -------- I get : getting https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all ------ + 1 https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all ------ - 0 https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all ----- then {source: network, level: 'error',
  text:
   'Failed to load resource: ... 404 (Not Found)', url:
   'https://render.activitree.com/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all',}

Comment: and in Nginx I have the usual: if ($prerender = 1) {
           set $prerender "127.0.0.1:3000";
           rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
           proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }

Comment: When I debug with a header sent back to curl, I get  $host is "render.activitree.com" and $request_uri is  "/https://act-test.herokuapp.com/activities/leisure/all"

Comment: Ok, things are ok for now. It looks that I don't need to rewrite and just pass to prerender as is. This is what works: if ($prerender = 1) {
           set $prerender "127.0.0.1:3000";
      
    
           proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }